# How do I gather a list of who a specific twitter user is following using twint?

Tags: python, pycharm, twitterapi-python, twint

I am trying to gather a list of users that follow a specific main user using twint in pycharm. I keep getting these errors when I run my code though.

```
CRITICAL:root:twint.get:User:'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
CRITICAL:root:twint.feed:Follow:IndexError
```

Here is my code:

```
import twint
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()
c = twint.Config()
c.Username = "brendan_webdev"
c.Followers = True
c.Resume = "resume.txt"
c.Output = "testing.csv"
twint.run.Following(c)
```

I have no idea why this isn't running. All the tutorials I have seen have had almost this exact code and seemed to work.

I also tried running command line for twint, but my machine won't recognize that twint exists on it.

I tried running this in command line as a test, after pip installing twint and cloning the repository.

```
twint -u "brendan_webdev"
```

Nothing seems to work. I have no idea why either.

Any help is appreciated!

Note: I am running Python 3.9 btw.

Comment: It may be that the current version of twint isn't very reliable. I just did a 'pip install twint' and ran:- twint -u <myusername> and it failed with the exact same error you're seeing. I'm on Python 3.9.6 and macOS 11.5

Comment: maybe they changed something on server and now module needs also changes and you may need to wait fro newer version. You could check on https://PyPi.org when last version was released.

Comment: `pypi.org` shows that [twint](https://pypi.org/project/twint/) is one year old - so it may have some bugs. There is also [twint-fork](https://pypi.org/project/twint-fork/) which was updated few weeks ago.

Comment: `pip3 install twint`

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting seems to be related to the version of twint that you are using.
Upgrade to the latest version using this command:

> pip3 install --upgrade -e git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint

This fixed the error for me.